# Problema con comando optim

Tags: r, rstudio

Necesito calcular el máximo de estas funciones con el comando `optim`, pero me devuelve errores

```
beneficio <- function(x){ 
(10 -9*x)*(exp(x^2 +1))  }
maximizarb <- optim(c(0), funcion1, method="L-BFGS-B", control=list(fnscale=-1)
```

Me da este error:

> Error in optim(c(0), beneficio, method = "L-BFGS-B", control = list(fnscale = -1)) : L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'

Si lo modifico como

```
max1 <- optim(c(1), funcion1, method="L-BFGS-B", control=list(fnscale=-1), lower=c(0))
```

Ahi no me da errores, pero no estoy segura de que este bien

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Parece que la función no alcanza un máximo usa el método de máximos y mínimos con derivadas, veras como las raíces de la primera derivada son completas.

También puedes gratificar la función para ver su comportamiento

```
beneficio <- function(x){ 
  print(x)
  (10 -9*x)*(exp(x^2 +1)) 

  }

x<-seq(-10,10,by=0.001)
y<-beneficio(x)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]